# Query that works in mySQL but not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query with 3 inserts and 3 updates which works great as is in sql (phpMyAdmin or Navicat etc). But when I put it through PHP it gives me an error 'invalid syntax'. When I break each insert and update to single query in PHP it works.

I need it to work in one query though for performance cause the query is intended for around 2mils of data. I use mysql.

Comment: Post some codes, otherwise we cant help you

Comment: Why do you _have to_ work in one query?

Comment: @Harti multiple queries can downgrade performance. *if possible* that you can do stuff in one query (excluding nested queries), the better. for example, querying two tables when you can do it in one query using a join.

Comment: @Joseph: Fair point, I knew this. 3 inserts and 3 updates don't sound like causing massive performance issues, though. :-)

Comment: @Harti - probably because OP isn't familiar with transactions

Comment: You can't have three inserts and three updates in one query. OP probably wants to run six queries with one call to mysql_query(); which as we all know will not work.

Comment: Let me get my magic ball.... Anyone saw it by the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't (and shouldn't) send multiple statements "in one query" (at least when using [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), wich is what i assume - but you havn't given information about if you're using that, [`PDO`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), [`mysqli`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or something else). sounds like you need them to be executed "all or nothing" - but thats what *transactions* are invented for. that said, the clean solution is:

1. use multiple querys
2. [read about transaction-management](http://dba.fyicenter.com/faq/mysql/mysql_sql_transaction_management.html) and use it

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have more than one SQL statement in one mysql_query().

Comment: No, but you can with mysqli... and OP hasn't told us whether he's using mysql, mysqli or pdo

Comment: True. Let's see if I guessed well ;-)